# Flex grid, horizontal with a vertical stack?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rc40bec4/)

I need to have a flex grid that looks like:

```
1|2
1|3
```

Item 1 is the entire height and items 2 and 3 are half the height. Is this possible without creating 2 flex grids?

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    flex-basis: 25%
}
li:first-child {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you set a height on the container?

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css

Comment: Or with height on container but whitout changing the order https://jsfiddle.net/rc40bec4/1/