# Make a div span two rows in a grid

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

I have a page full of blocks which pile up with `display: inline-block`. I want to make some four or two times bigger, so I used `float: left` or `right` to put other blocks around.

My problem is if I have a **five-element row**, how could I put a bigger element **in the middle** of it? (as `float` put it naturally on the side).

Here's an example snippet:

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 516px;
}
.block{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bigger{
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Here's what I would like to have from the snippet above [image: Expected]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Flexbox Solution

You have fixed heights on your child elements (`.block`). Based on that information, we can extrapolate the height of the container (`#wrapper`).

By knowing the height of the container, your layout can be achieved using [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) with `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

A fixed height on the container serves as a breakpoint, telling flex items where to wrap.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 120px;
  width: 516px;
}
.block {
  width: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bigger {
  flex-basis: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hncjr854/)

Here's an explanation why flex items can't wrap unless there's a fixed height/width on the container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43897663/3597276

Comment: I love flex layout so I really like this answer ! But what if you didn't knew the wrapper height ?

Answer (score 17):

### Grid Solution

For your layout to work with flexbox, you need to *use nested containers* or *know the height of the container* ([see my other answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099207/3597276)). Not so with Grid. The code structure is very simple.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;                                     /* 1 */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 90px);            /* 2 */
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;                              /* 3 */
  grid-gap: 10px;                                    /* 4 */
  width: 516px;
}
.bigger {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;                                   /* 5 */
  grid-column: 2 / 3;                                /* 6 */
}
.block {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3580upfo/)

Notes:

1. Establish a block-level grid container. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-containers))
2. Instruct the grid to create a 90px width column, and repeat the process 5 times. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#repeat-notation))
3. Grid rows will be created *implicitly* (i.e., automatically, as necessary). Each implicit row should have a 50px height. ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks))
4. The gutters around grid items. `grip-gap` is shorthand for `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap`.([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters))
5. Instruct the large item to span from row lines 1 to 3. (There are three row lines in a two-row grid.)  ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands)).
6. Instruct the large item to span from grid column lines 2 to 3. (There are six column lines in a five-column grid.) ([spec reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands))