# How can I make a div span multiple rows and columns in a grid?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid-layout, css-grid

Building off of [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/alternative-to-css-grid-layout-but-not-tables), I'm trying to add bigger blocks to my grid layout. In the last question, I needed to have a div span multiple rows. The problem now is that I need a div to span multiple rows *and columns*.

If I have a **five-element row**, how could I put bigger elements **in the middle** of it? (as `float` puts it naturally on the side).

Here's an example snippet:

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 516px;
}
.block{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bigger{
  height: 110px;
}
.larger{
  height: 110px;
  width: 190px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block larger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use [`display: grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for the wrapper element, as *Can I Use* [states](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) this is a pretty on-the-edge technology right now. I was hoping for a **non-grid**, **non-table** solution.

Here's what I would like to have from the snippet above [image: Expected]

Comment: Can the HTML be altered?

Comment: If your HTML cannot be altered, I'd suggest using a library like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) - not sure there's a pure CSS solution that will really accomplish what you're going for.

Comment: @Michael_B I am working on a '2 block wrapper' but would love another way to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping your HTML as-is, the layout is not natively possible with flexbox. This is primarily because of the 2 x 2 box occupying the third and fourth columns. The closest you can get is this:

```css
#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 180px;
  width: 516px;
}
.block {
  width: 90px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.bigger{
  flex-basis: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the big box is broken up between columns.

As mentioned in the [other post you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42946454/3597276), since you have fixed heights on your child elements (`.block`), we can determine the height of the container (`.wrapper`).

By knowing the height of the container, the layout above can be achieved using `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap: wrap`.

A fixed height on the container serves as a breakpoint, telling flex items where to wrap.

Alternatively, if you can add containers, then the layout is easy. Just create four nested flex containers to hold columns 1, 2, 3-4 and 5, and you're done.

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 516px;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.bigger {
  flex-basis: 110px;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

section:nth-child(3)>.block:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 190px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="block bigger"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Otherwise, see this post for more details and other options:

- [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)

Answer (score 28):

I understand that you are seeking an answer that doesn't involve *HTML Tables* or *CSS Grid Layout*. You mention that you don't want Grid because of weak browser support.

However, around the same time you posted your question, most major browsers released new versions which provide full support for Grid Layout (see details below).

---

[**CSS Grid**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/) makes your layout simple. There is no need to alter your HTML, add nested containers or set a fixed height on the container ([see my flexbox answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43125050/3597276)).

```css
#wrapper {
  display: grid;                            /* 1 */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 90px);   /* 2 */
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;                     /* 3 */
  grid-gap: 10px;                           /* 4 */
  width: 516px;
}

.tall {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;                          /* 5 */
  grid-column: 2 / 3;                       /* 5 */
}

.wide {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;                          /* 6 */
  grid-column: 3 / 5;                       /* 6 */
}

.block {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block tall"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block wide"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4qg47bLq/1/)

How it works:

1. [Establish a block-level grid container.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-containers)
2. The [**`grid-template-columns`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing) property sets the width of explicitly defined columns. In this case, the grid is instructed to create a 90px width column, and repeat the process 5 times.
3. The [**`grid-auto-rows`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#auto-tracks) property sets the height of automatically generated (*implicit*) rows. Here each row is 50px tall.
4. The [**`grid-gap`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#gutters) property is a shorthand for `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap`. This rule sets a 10px gap *between* grid items. (It doesn't apply to the area between items and the container.)
5. [Instruct the `.tall` item to span from row lines 1 to 3 and column lines 2 to 3.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands)*
6. [Instruct the `.wide` item to span from row lines 2 to 4 and column lines 3 to 5.](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands)*

<sup>* In a five-column grid there are six column lines. In a three-row grid there are four row lines.</sup>

---

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: This is great!  Do you know how I can have an arbitrary box grow in size without any knowledge of its peers?

Comment: @SB2055, can you provide a bit more detail? Maybe a demo to work off of? Or consider posting a new question with full detail.

Answer (score 1):

To make it with flexbox and flex-direction: row.

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 516px;
  display: flex;         /* added */
  flex-flow: row wrap;   /* added */
}
.block{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.block:last-child {
  margin-left: 205px;    /* added */
}
.bigger{
  height: 110px;
  margin-bottom: -55px;  /* added */
}
.larger{
  height: 110px;
  width: 190px;
  margin-left: 105px;    /* added */
  margin-bottom: -55px;  /* added */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block bigger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block larger"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```