# Move 3rd item under 2nd in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an image with center aligned text to the right, but I need the 3rd element which I have named "title", Founder, to stack under the second item named "name" Dewey Stringer. You can see what I am trying to achieve https://seewebgo.com/aas/advisory-board/

I can't seem to add any code in here, but it is visible by going to the page.

```css
.box {
   display: flex;
   align-items:center;
}
img.round{
border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
margin: 30px 30px 30px 0;
}
.page-id-95 .box .name{
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 500;
}
.page-id-95 .box .title{
color: #ccc;
text-transform: uppercase;
align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><img src="https://seewebgo.com/aas/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/dewey-photo.jpg" alt="" width="202" height="202" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-175 round" /><p class="name">Dewey Stringer</p><p class="title">Founder</p></div>
</div>

<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia.</p>
```

Comment: Can you have a fixed height on the `.box` container?

Comment: Why would I need to add a fixed height? When it goes mobile that will be a problem?

Comment: It's explained in the duplicate. Here's how it would work for you in flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/d1jw9q2g/1/

Comment: OK, that worked, could you please explain a little???

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to flex, so not quite grasping the why's and wherefore's

Comment: Please read the duplicate post for an explanation of the flex concepts involved in the solution. That post also provides an alternative solution, using CSS Grid. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43897663/3597276) for additional details.

Comment: Thank you for your help