# CSS dynamic columns inside single container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a system that will create a dynamic column layout inside a *single container*, but I am not sure if this is doable. For reference, see this code:

```css
.rekt {
  width: 422px;
  background-color: beige;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rekt .row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: royalblue;
  width: 97.5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.rekt span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster1</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster2</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster3</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster4</span>
    <div class='row'>Cassandra</div>
    <div class='row'>Mongo</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster5</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster6</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/wa23/pen/WOMGxp

So, each `rekt` lies inside a single container, the `flexbox`, but each `rekt` could have a variable height, depending on how many `row` the user inserts into it.

Ideally, you'd have smaller ones like cluster 2,3, and 4 be grouped together into one column, while cluster6 would be in its own column because it is enormous.

I tried using flexbox:

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

But this did not work as expected. I know these bounds sound contrived, but it is how the system is set up.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the change you are looking for on top of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned you tried the code below and it didn't work:

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

It probably didn't work because you didn't specify a height on the container. Without a fixed height, the flex items wouldn't know where to wrap.

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXvaPK)

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 100vh;
}
.rekt {
  width: 422px;
  background-color: beige;
  /* height: 100%; */
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  /* margin-bottom: 10px; */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.row {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: royalblue;
  width: 97.5%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster1</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster2</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster3</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster4</span>
    <div class='row'>Cassandra</div>
    <div class='row'>Mongo</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster5</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
  </div>

  <div class='rekt'>
    <span>Cluster6</span>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>foo</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
    <div class='row'>bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More information:

- [Make a div span two rows in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42946454/3597276)
- [When flexbox items wrap in column mode, container does not grow its width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33891709/3597276)