# Creating an end-of-row "cell" that uses 100% of a flex table's "row height", regardless of other items' flex wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, css-tables

I am currently creating flex tables that, for middleware reasons, will still use `<table>` elements but with flex styling.  I would like the ability to have the first and/or last cell of each `<tr>` span the entire row height while the other items wrap in between.

Goal:
[image: final goal]

One way to solve this is to switch to a div-based table.  The wrapping content is contained in a separate div from the non-wrapping first & last cells, and the child "cells" wrap inside this parent.  However this approach causes problems with the existing middleware infrastructure (customer configs, table sorting & paginating, etc).  Inserting divs into a `<table>` structure is also a no-go due to how browsers render `<table>` elements.

Codepen demo with a responsive table and a desired-end-state div-based table: https://codepen.io/shrakner/pen/xmBQKx

Hopefully there's some flexbox trickery that can accomplish this and I just haven't stumbled across it yet- I'm interested in any suggestions or alternative ways of approaching this problem!

Comment: Did you add an external image? COuld you upload it here directly?

Comment: Also, you could add media property to first and the last child of rows to achieve this. Something like [this](https://codepen.io/BlueSpirit/pen/bOZPKm)

Comment: Not unless you know the height of each row....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/make-a-div-span-two-rows-in-a-grid