# Equal Image height within columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place some images in two columns.
One image in the left column and two images in the right column. 
The two images in the right column should have the same height as the image in the left. How can I achieve this ?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnmU8.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/4.jpg" alt="">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="img/4.jpg" alt="">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>

.hero-header{
  position: relative;
}

.hero-headline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Please could you share the CSS that you have tried so far so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: What you have there is **three** columns...not two.

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/make-a-div-span-two-rows-in-a-grid

Answer (score -1):

Just use your already created class **img-responsive** and set **height:100%** or whatever number your are looking for. Like this, all the images will have the same height for sure.