# Grid List Float Left

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Can you help me understaing why the white shirts images go next line and not below the blue ones?

[image: Material UI Grid list]

I'm using material ui for reactjs:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
    <GridList cellHeight={100} cols={4} rows={2}>
        <GridListTile rows={2} cols={2}>
            <img src="https://..." />
        </GridListTile>
        <GridListTile>
            <img src="https://..." />
        </GridListTile>
        <GridListTile>
            <img src="https://..." />
        </GridListTile>
        <GridListTile>
            <img src="https://..." />
        </GridListTile>
        <GridListTile>
            <img src="https://..." />
        </GridListTile>
    </GridList>
</Grid>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: for clearness this is the searched result:

[image: wanted result]

And this is the code snippet:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-drawer-demo-3txbo

Comment: change `cols={4}` by `cols={2}` here's the codesanbox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-drawer-demo-lqi10

Comment: But I want the white shirts UNDER the blue one, keeping the big one on the left...

Comment: You're not using `float`...its flexbox based and flexbox can't do that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/make-a-div-span-two-rows-in-a-grid

Comment: @Paulie_D: thanks, what do you suggest?