# Wrap multiple small items next to one large item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

The goal I'm trying to archive is the following:

[image: Wrapping multiple items]

I would like to wrap multiple items around one large item. If possible, I would like to avoid nesting the items into another div, because then I might loose the easy opportunity to re-order items.

One item will always be at the most left/top position. This item might dynamically change, with the class `item-active`. So, ordering of the items is something that I would like to take into account. That got me to choose Flexbox. CSS-Grid might also be attempting as a solution, but I'm a little concerned about browser support.

I tried to fiddle around a bit, but couldn't come up with a satisfying solution:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 3rem;  
  
  width: 25%;
}

.item-active { order: 1; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

.item-1 { background: #3CFF8A }
.item-2 { background: #3CFFC0 }
.item-3 { background: #3CFFF4 }
.item-4 { background: #3CD4FF }
.item-5 { background: #3C9FFF }
.item-6 { background: #3C6EFF }
.item-7 { background: #3C56FF }
.item-8 { background: #583CFF }
.item-9 { background: #8D3CFF }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 item-active">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
</div>
```

I thought using `flex-wrap` + `flex-direction` with a item positioned absolute could solve it. Unfortunately not.

- What is missing to archive it?
- Would it even be possible to archive it with flexbox?
- Flexbox is one-dimensional. Does my requirement already count as two-dimensional?

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? Can you explain whats still missing in reference to the picture above?

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what `CSS Float` is intended to do...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42946454/3597276

Comment: @davidev In my solution the items are behind the big block, because of position it absolute. It's 9 items in total, only 7 are shown

Comment: @Michael_B Oh well thank you for pointing out this thread. `flex-basis` for the rescue? I will have to look up this property in more detail. But it seems very promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done using CSS grid which is more suitable than flexbox since what you have is a two-dimensional grid.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(6,1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(3,50px);
  grid-gap:5px;
  margin:5px;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;  
}

.item-active {
   grid-column:1/span 3;
   grid-row:1/span 3;
}

.item-1 { background: #3CFF8A }
.item-2 { background: #3CFFC0 }
.item-3 { background: #3CFFF4 }
.item-4 { background: #3CD4FF }
.item-5 { background: #3C9FFF }
.item-6 { background: #3C6EFF }
.item-7 { background: #3C56FF }
.item-8 { background: #583CFF }
.item-9 { background: #8D3CFF }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 item-active">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 ">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5 item-active">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9 item-active">9</div>
</div>
```

Using flexbox it can be done with some *hacks*

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;  
  height:50px;
  width:calc(100%/6 - 10px);
  margin:5px;
}

.item-active {
  order:-1;
  width:calc(100%/2 - 10px);
  height:calc(150px + 20px);
  margin-bottom:calc(-100px - 20px);
}

.item-active:nth-child(-n + 4) ~ :nth-child(5),
.item-active:nth-child(-n + 7) ~ :nth-child(8){
  margin-left:calc(100%/2 + 5px)
}

.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(7){
  margin-left:calc(100%/2 + 5px)
}
.item-active:nth-child(-n + 4) ~ :nth-child(4),
.item-active:nth-child(-n + 7) ~ :nth-child(7){
 margin-left:5px;
}


.item-1 { background: #3CFF8A }
.item-2 { background: #3CFFC0 }
.item-3 { background: #3CFFF4 }
.item-4 { background: #3CD4FF }
.item-5 { background: #3C9FFF;}
.item-6 { background: #3C6EFF }
.item-7 { background: #3C56FF }
.item-8 { background: #583CFF;}
.item-9 { background: #8D3CFF }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 item-active">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2 ">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5 item-active">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9">9</div>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item item-1">1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">2<br><br></div>
  <div class="item item-3">3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">4</div>
  <div class="item item-5">5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">8</div>
  <div class="item item-9  item-active">9</div>
</div>
```