# Aligning a layout with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/Aspiring/pen/yLbwrOe

```css
.flex-container {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 250px;
}

.topheader {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="topheader">Head</div>

  <div class="content">

    <header>Hello</header>
    <main>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni voluptas odio repellat facilis officia
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to align the `div.sidebar` and `div.topheader` of my layout to where they will scale correctly with my page and I can use the `div.flex-container` to input the main content and articles, I'm basically making a Wiki style page for practice and understanding of flexbox. Additional information on best practice or resources other than MDN would be much appreciated.

[image]

I did additional editing in trying to solve my own issue, using what I know and got as far as the image shown... The is messy so i just left the orgianl unedited code on the codepen

Just starting flexbox and learning.

Comment: This is a great article about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: personally I would recommend to go for CSS-Grid in your case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42946454/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Flexbox:**

Flexbox can only control height or width. It can not control both at the same time. As such you need 2 flexbox wrappers as shown in the snippet below

```css
.flex-container-horizontal {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 50%;
}

.flex-container-vertical {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}

/* for styling pupose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
}

.topheader {
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-horizontal">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="flex-container-vertical">
    <div class="topheader">Head</div>
    <div class="content">
      <header>Hello</header>
      <main>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni voluptas odio repellat facilis officia
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## **CSS-Grid:**

The more appropiate tool in your case would be CSS-Grid. Only downside is that it is only partially supported by IE. However IE will be started to be deprecated at the 16th August 2021. You either can use `span` as in my example or use `grid-template-areas`. Grid can control both height and width at the same time.

```css
.grid-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content auto;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-row: span 2;
}


/* for styling pupose only */

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: red;
}

.topheader {
  background-color: blue;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="topheader">Head</div>
  <div class="content">
    <header>Hello</header>
    <main>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni voluptas odio repellat facilis officia
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explaination, @tacoshy!