# CSS grids layout adjustment to the content

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

I'm trying to set my grid layout as follows:

[image: grid layout -]

Is it even possible? The issue I'm having is when the content in item #3 is getting bigger it expands item #2 and pushes it down. Is there any way to avoid such behavior when content is large at item #3?

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.grid-element {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  background-color: wheat;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='grid-element'>1</div>
  <div class='grid-element'>2</div>
  <div class='grid-element'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just edited my post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/make-a-div-span-two-rows-in-a-grid

Answer (score 1):

example code for responsive grid with css.repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)); and overflow-wrap: break-word; added for fit content.

```
<style>
    .item1 {
        grid-area: area1;
    }

    .item2 {
        grid-area: area2;
    }

    .item3 {
        grid-area: area3;
    }

    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 'area1 area1 area1 area2 area2'
                             'area1 area1 area1 area2 area2'
                             'area1 area1 area1 area3 area3'
                             'area1 area1 area1 area3 area3';
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
        background-color: #2196F3;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }

        .grid-container > div {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 0;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
</style>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item1">3</div>
        <div class="item2">2</div>
        <div class="item3">1</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I have understood your question correctly or not, but I hope the following snippet could be helpful:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
      grid-template-areas: "d1 d3" "d2 d3";
    }
    
    .container>div:nth-child(1) {
      grid-area: d1;
    }
    
    .container>div:nth-child(2) {
      grid-area: d2;
    }
    
    .container>div:nth-child(3) {
      grid-area: d3;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div style="background-color: blue;">item1</div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow;">item2</div>
    <div style="background-color: orangered;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum facere facilis reprehenderit corporis, iure dolorum harum suscipit ratione fuga iste rem laboriosam aut perspiciatis libero nostrum praesentium? Quae, illum sed?</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).