# How can I use CSS grid to create the following layout?

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I am using CSS grid to collage three images. However, I can not get the last two smaller images where they need to be. Currently, in the browser, the two small images are above the first large image. Any help welcome.

[image]

In CSS I have:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1].collage {
    float: left;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    -ms-grid-columns:1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    gap: 10px;
}
.collage__img:first-child {
      grid-row-start: row1-start;
      grid-row-end: 2;
      grid-column-start: 1;
      grid-column-end: 1;
}
.collage__img:nth-child(2){
     grid-row-start: row1-start;
     grid-row-end: 1;
     grid-column-start: 2;
     grid-column-end: 2;
}
.collage__img:nth-child(3){
    grid-row-start: row2-start;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 2;
}
```

Comment: You're using grid line names but you haven't defined them anywhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946454/make-a-div-span-two-rows-in-a-grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;  
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
}
.container div {
    background: red;    
}
.container .item1{
    grid-row: 1 / span 2    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">1</div>
    <div class="item2">2</div>
    <div class="item3">3</div>
</div>
```