# CSS Flexbox - First child to be equal height

Tags: css, flexbox

What I am trying to achieve is when the layout breaks down to mobile the image block matches the same height as the title/content blocks.

The layout is quite tricky, it works as expected on desktop view with the title block being at the top full width. I think the issue is using flex-wrap: wrap on the mobile view? (I have got this layout working using CSS grid but unfortunately it cannot be used on production)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.title {
  background: tomato;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  background: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
}

.content {
  background: gold;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">img</div>
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8dvhew3q/4/

Comment: "*[It's] working using CSS grid but unfortunately it cannot be used on production*" - why?

Comment: Have to support older browsers, and autoprefixer doesn't solve the display issues on them

Comment: Essentially, not possible with flexbox and the current structure.

Comment: No chance without JavaScript

Comment: Perhaps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css

Comment: Ah I see thanks anyway! I may have to duplicate the title inside the content block as a work around

Answer (score -2):

use this code

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.title,
.image,
.content {
  width: 50%;
}

.title {
  background: tomato;
}

.image {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.content {
  background: gold;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .title {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }

  .image {
    order: 2;
    height: 150px;
  }

  .content {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```