# How to create a column oriented layout using materialize?

Tags: html, css, layout, materialize

I am trying to place two cards among each other beside one larger card using the materialize framework.

The code I am currently using looks like this:

```
<div class="row">   
<div class="col s6">
      <div class="card-panel">        
          <div class="card-content">
          <h5 class="blue-grey-text text-lighten-2">p1</h5>
          </div>      
      </div>
</div>
<div class="col s6">
      <div class="card-panel">
        <div class="card-content">
          <h5 class="blue-grey-text text-lighten-2">p3</h5> 
        </div>    
      </div>
</div>
<div class="col s6">
      <div class="card-panel">        
          <div class="card-content">
          <h5 class="blue-grey-text text-lighten-2">p2</h5>
          </div>      
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: img1]

But I would like to place `p1` and `p2` directly beside `p3`, so that the layout looks like this:

[image: img2]

Is this somehow possible using materialize?

Comment: If it uses flexbox *kinda* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css

Comment: Try to keep p1 and p2 in first col s6 and p3 in another; this may resolve your issue.

Comment: @prashant yes this solved my problem. Such I simple solution, but I really didn't come up with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s6">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
         P1
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
          p2
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col s6">
      P3
   <div>
</div>
```