# How to make responsive grid design using boostrap (placement issue)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid-layout, mobile-website

I m new to bootstrap, how can make this layout?

https://ibb.co/F7mv5V6

[image: my design picture]

This is what I have tried, but wrong (it must be such as picture link)

```
     <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">A</div>   
     <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">X</div>  
                    <div class="col">Y</div>  
            </div>
     </div>   
     <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">B</div>
```

Comment: You may need to duplicate code for `X`.

Comment: Please have a look at bootstrap `class="order-**-**"`

Comment: Not possible with BS/Flexbox - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css - Also see `display:contents`.

Answer (score -2):

Check this if it helps.

```css
.bg{background-color:#f1f1f1; width:100%; height:100%}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="bg">A</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="bg">X</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="bg">Y</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="bg">B</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Incorrect order in mobile

Comment: @Kevin I tried your code but it is wrong in mobile view, result is same as my wrong code,  it should be X A Y B please check the image link