# Split a sidebar in top and bottom on mobile with CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is it possible to split a sidebar with css grids on mobile but treat it kind of one on desktop?

On mobile I want everything stacked *Intro* *Part of the sidebar* *Content* and then the rest of the *Sidebar*.

On desktop I would like *Intro* and *Content* stacked in one column and the 2 sidebars stacked next to them.

The closes I got was

```
grid-template-areas:
  "intro"
  "sidebarTop"
  "content"
  "sidebarBottom";
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  grid-template-areas:
    "intro sidebarTop"
    "content sidebarTop"
    "content sidebarBottom";
}
```

But sidebarTop always takes up as much space as it can.
I want it to only use the space it uses and let the sidebarBottom take up the rest.

Any suggestions?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/181rZ.jpg)

Comment: Is the example how you want it? or the example of how it is now?

Comment: CSS-Grid is not an option here as your image shows that this *is not a grid* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css

Answer (score -1):

You can start with something like this, then adapt each block to your need:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
  grid-template-areas: "intro" "sidebarTop" "content" "sidebarBottom";
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 33.33%);
    grid-template-areas: "intro sidebarTop" "content sidebarTop" "content sidebarBottom";
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="intro">
    intro
  </section>
  <section id="sidebarTop">
    sidebarTop
  </section>
  <section id="content">
    content
  </section>
  <section id="sidebarBottom">
    sidebarBottom
  </section>
</main>
```