# how do this position of blocks

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need two blocks in left column and one block in right block on desktop. And then one block from right column must be between two block from left columns and this fullwidth. From this [image: from-this]
to this
[image: to-this]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="text-top">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
</div>
<div class="text-bottom">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
</div>
<img src="some_image.png" />
```

Image is a red block

Comment: add code snippet

Comment: I add code snippet

Comment: answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css