# Flexbox break at second Element

Tags: html, jquery, css, flexbox

Good day,
is it possible with flexbox to force a break after the second element and then just put it underneath? [image]

```css
.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 33.333%;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No this is not possible unless using column direction and a known height. You want CSS-Grid

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947885/left-column-and-stacked-right-column-using-flexbox-css

Comment: With this html is not possible... in this case better use grid

Comment: That is THE use-case to opt for CSS `grid` as it supports multi-dimensional columns and rows while flex-box just supports either rows or columns. https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.app/ may be an introductory tool that aids you if you are not familiar with grid.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to use the grid, but you can use the column direction and give the height of columns 1 and 4 to 100% and 2 and 3 to the extent that the total reaches 100%.